# Why is 'source_stringstream' is empty after 'dest_stringstream << source_stringstream.rdbuf()'? Why eofbit is not set?

Tags: c++, stringstream

1) I would like to send information from one stringstream to several another stringstreams. But in the exapmle below it seems that after **<< in_contents.rdbuf();**, in_contests is empty.  What operation should I use in order to I avoid it?

2)Why **eofbit** and **failbit** is not set in **in_contents** after abovementioned operation as may be in the case **std::getline(in_contents, word)**? I've moved an entire buffer, but ...

Thank you!

```
std::stringstream in_contents("gg");
std::stringstream out_contents1;
std::stringstream out_contents2;

out_contents1 << in_contents.rdbuf();  //make in_contents buffer empty?

in_contents.seekg(0);
out_contents2 << in_contents.rdbuf();//out_contents2 has nothing

cout << endl << in_contents.eof();//zero?
cout << endl << in_contents.fail();//zero?
//std::getline(in_contents, word);//failbit=1; eofbit=1?
```

Comment: Since you are operating directly on the underlying buffer, how should the stream even get a chance to set its eof bit?

Comment: I think the stream buffers on that line which is the reason you are seeing no output.

Comment: Successfully reading what you tried to read doesn't traditionally set `eof`, not just in C++ but in any language I've only ever seen the condition flagged when you tried to read something and it wasn't there.

Comment: What about `out_contents1 << in_contents.str();`? (you could also store that string in a local variable to avoid getting multiple copies)